# How to convert product subtype to product master subtype?

Tags: axapta, product, dynamics-ax-2012

I work in AX 2012, in Product Information Management List Page, is there any way to convert from Product subtype to product master subtype?

What is the process while releasing the produt/ product master subtype?

First create product -> then move that to product master -> then release it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a Product sub type once its been created.

They are created in distinct tables EcoResProductMaster and EcoResDistinctProduct.

Here is a nice guide to the process of creating and releasing products

http://ramdynamicsax.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/creation-of-item-or-product-and-product-master-in-dynamics-ax-2012/